# How to add column in the dynamic table with colspan?

Tags: angular, primeng, business-logic, primeng-table

I need to add columns in the table with colspan.

So basically there are 4 tables with multi headers. I need to add columns in the last two headers' basics of the green, blue, and pink checkbox. When the user checks any checkbox the column adds and the first header colspan increase with the respective column.

See [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tabledynamic-demo-h58rsj)

These are the ref images.
For one check
[image]

For Both check
[image]

PLz, help me to solve these queries. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

not sure what the problem is. should be pretty simple.

html:

```
<td colspan="{{numCols}}">
```

.ts:

```
this.numCols = (checkBoxChecked)?4:3;
```